# Why java substring not working in this case?

Tags: java

I've written a code where java code selects digit before decimal point in different variable and digits after decimal point in different variable. For example in the below code we have 23.256 Now the code that i have written will select 23 in `firstDigit` variable and .256 in `lastDigit` variable. Now problem comes when there is no digits after decimal point for example if we have 23 this will crash.

**What I've written is (THIS WORKS)**

```
totalAmount = 23.256;
String totalAmountString = new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(totalAmount )).toString();
String firstDigit= totalAmountString .substring( 0,totalAmountString .indexOf('.'));
String lastDigit= totalAmountString .substring( totalAmountString .indexOf('.'), totalAmountString .length());
```

**It doesn't work**

```
totalAmount = 23;
String totalAmountString = new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(totalAmount )).toString();
String firstDigit= totalAmountString .substring( 0,totalAmountString .indexOf('.'));
String lastDigit= totalAmountString .substring( totalAmountString .indexOf('.'), totalAmountString .length());
```

totalAmount will be provided by user so we don't know if there will digit after decimal point or not. Problem when user enters the totalAmount without any digit after decimal point the code crashes.

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: You need to check wether there is a decimal present or not in the string. After that you may proceed with `substring()`.

Comment: How do i do that ?

Comment: You can use `contains('.')`

Comment: I'm very new to java. I've just started learning. So can you please share the code , because i don't know how do i use that ??

Comment: Check my answer made for you here https://stackoverflow.com/a/63067665/10458040

Answer (score 1):

You need to first check if the index is `-1`, meaning that no decimal point was found.

```
int idx = totalAmountString .indexOf('.');
String firstDigit=  idx != -1 ? totalAmountString .substring( 0, idx): totalAmountString;
String lastDigit= idx != -1 ? totalAmountString .substring(idx, getAcreIntoString.length()): "";
```

Comment: It will return `-1`

Comment: For example if user enter 25 it should give 25 only and if 25.235 then it should give 25 in one variable and .235 in another . -1 will not work for it.

Answer (score 1):

The following code worked for me.

```
double totalAmount = 23.256;
String totalAmountInString = String.valueOf(totalAmount).toString();
//Checks wether the totalAmount has value after decimal     
if (totalAmount % 1 != 0)
{
     //totalAmount has value after decimal
     String firstDigit = totalAmountInString.substring( 0,totalAmountInString .indexOf('.'));
     String lastDigit= totalAmountInString.substring( totalAmountInString.indexOf('.'), totalAmountInString.length());
     System.out.println("Before Decimal : " + firstDigit);
     System.out.println("After Decimal : " + lastDigit);
}
else
{
     //totalAmount has no value after decimal
     System.out.println(totalAmountInString + " Has no decimal");
}
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Can you please provide me code by using my above given code, As i'm very new to java so i don't know how to use that ?

Comment: Because i'm using java switch so i don't know how to use if else with in java switch

Comment: You can use the above code instead of your code quoted inside the question

Comment: You asked a question and someone provided a working solution. Why do you want it to perfectly fit to your (not working) code above? If you do not know how to use if/else, then I would probably a good idea to learn it, since it is no rocket science.
If you need this as solution for an assignment ... well thats not what this platform is for anyway.

Comment: @Seb well i learned it and tried with the above solution. But the problem is we can not use variable outside if else which are defined within if else. I also tried by defining null variable with same name outside if else and then updated them within if else that didn't work too. Thats why i asked him to provide some detailed code.

Comment: Have a look here: https://www.baeldung.com/java-variable-scope

Answer (score 0):

You can use split method of String class

```
   String totAmountStr = new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(23.256)).toString();
    String[] split = totAmountStr.split("\\.");
    String firstDigit= null;
    String lastDigit= null;;
    if (split.length > 1) {
         firstDigit = split[0];
         lastDigit = split[1];
    } else {
         firstDigit = split[0];
    }
```

Comment: If i use it as it is. IT is working, but how do i use that with my above code. I'm new to java so don't know much about. Can you please tell me how do i use with my code above ?

Comment: what exactly you want to do with firstDigit and lastDigit.
At the end of iteration you will get values for firstDigit and lastDigit

I have edited my answer see if this make any sense to you

Comment: That's not the end program will take those value to further and where another calculation will take place. And again it will check if there is decimal or not.

Comment: @user45154754514656210 share complete code where you want to fit in this piece of code